# sass files are not working in Cactus 1.0.1

Tags: sass

I am using Cactus 1.0.1. In my html I am using .scss file. As per the Cactus documentation, the .scss file will be support in cactus without installing any additional things. But it is not working and the page was rendered without stylesheet. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the .scss file into .css and make sure there is no errors parsed.
Your html page has to have the path to the .css file and not the .scss

To compile the .scss file you need to have sass installed in your local machine.
Here is the documentation on how to install and use sass
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/

Comment: Hi Hichem Ben. Thanks a lot. It is working fine :). One thing we have to notice that if you use cactus you don't need to install sass in your machine. Cactus will do the compilation work and generate css files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Gnaneswaran, did you happen to create the .scss in its own sass directory, next to the css directory? If so, the corresponding .css file should be sitting in the same directory as your .scss file.

If that's the case you need to change the location of the style sheet in the head of your html file.

Comment: Hi Ed Sherry.. the corresponding .css file is sitting in the same directory which containing the .scss files. As per Hichem Ben statement my problem was solved. :) Thanks